# Hide top navigation links in displayform, editform Sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007

Everytime you open an item you can see navigation links on top of the page that lets you go back to the list.

Is there a way to hide those links? (screenshots below)

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, from my good old 2003 days (and still works in all versions)

You need JavaScript and CSS skills.

There are many ways to achieve what you want, maybe the easiest is:

- Browse to a New Form/Edit Form
- examine using F12 developer tools what JavaScript is required to hide those elements

Note: no need for jQuery, something like:

```
document.getElementById('[the id you explored]').style.display='none';
```

should be enough

- Add `&toolpaneview=2` to the end of the URL and press enter

  more url magic: http://sharethepunto.blogspot.nl/2014/06/sharepoint-url-tricks.html
- The page is now opened in Edit-mode
- Add a Content Editor WebPart
- Add the JavaScript required to hide the elements between `<script>[your code]</script>`tags
- Save the page

Tip: do not put the code inside the CEWP but link to an external JS file (not sure if this was possible in 2007) you put somewhere in a library.

*One file to rule them all*

Comment: thank you very much! i have tried to locate the ID using F12 with no luck... i succesfully hid the Home button using this code                                                                                               <style type="text/css"> #zz1_TopNavigationMenun0 { display: none !important; } </style>                 but i cant seem to find the ID for the links i need to hide

Comment: Google for **CSS selectors**, you can use those in a ``document.querySelector([**CSS selector**]).style.display='none';`` also