# Can 'Save' button text be changed to 'Submit' on SharePoint List forms -SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can 'Save' button text be changed to 'Submit' on SharePoint List forms -SharePoint Online

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to load a 90 Kilobyte jQuery library or loop thru elements

standard JavaScript  *** contains** Selector:

```
document.querySelector("a[id*='Commit'] span:nth-child(2)").innerHTML='Submit';
```

Or shorter and changing only one button on screen

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[id*='Commit']")[1].innerHTML='Submit';
```

And to add script to the Form: [Hide top navigation links in displayform, editform Sharepoint 2007](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163445/hide-top-navigation-links-in-displayform-editform-sharepoint-2007/163480#163480)

Answer (score 0):

I have done it this way, you could add this script to your master page...

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-cui-ctl-largelabel"); //The save button class
var i = 0;
while (i<x.length)
{
    if (x[i].innerHTML=="Save")
    x[i].innerHTML = "Submit";
    i++;
}
```

Of course it's not the best option since they can change the class name in the future or something else, but it works right now.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use jQuery and the [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), they'll probably not change the ID's.

```
$("id^='Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Commit.Publish']").children("span:eq(1)").text("Submit");
```

I haven't looked much into the [SP.Ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee549700(v=office.14).aspx) namespace tbh, so from what I can see you'll probably have to do something in the lines of this:

```
SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance()
    .get_ribbon()
    .getChild("Ribbon.ListForm.Edit")
    .getChild("Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Commit")
    .getChild("Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Commit-LargeLarge")
    .getChild("Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Commit-LargeLarge-0")
    .getChild("Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Commit-LargeLarge-0-0")
    .getChild("Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Commit.Publish-Large0")
    .$N_1.$G_1.children[1].innerText = "Submit";
```

I just hope thats not the correct way to use the SP.Ribbon namespace to alter existing elements, just hope someone has a better solution.